# Apply function to each element of a column and add result to a new column

Tags: r

How can I apply the ppois() function to each element of a column, and have the resultant p-value output into a new column in the same data frame?

For example, if I have a data frame of names and ages:

```
name  age
James  12
Allie  22
```

I would like the resultant data frame to be:

```
name  age  pvalue
James  12  0.0056
Allie  22  0.0023
```

I have tried doing:

```
mydata$pvalue <- ppois(mydata$age, lambda=lambda.age, lower=FALSE)
```

But this just gives the same p-value for each row. The actual data I have is 6 million rows long, so I'm looking for the fastest and most efficient option. I could use apply, as suggested in other questions, but that would require writing a function which would just contain the ppois() function, which seems a bad work-around.

Comment: What is `lambda.age`?

Comment: `ppois` should work just fine with a vector: `ppois(c(12,30, 40), 40, lower=FALSE)`. are you sure it's not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work -  I don't know why it doesn't, but this is also pretty easy to do with the `dplyr` package.

```
data = data.frame(name=c("James","Allie","Tom","Susan"),age=c(12,22,15,9))
lambda.age = 3
data %>%
  mutate(pvalue=ppois(age,lambda=lambda.age,lower=F)
#>    name age       pvalue
   1 James  12 1.614905e-05
   2 Allie  22 2.070411e-13
   3   Tom  15 1.240802e-07
   4 Susan   9 1.102488e-03
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick - you're absolutely correct.  I changed the language to try and better reflect the idea that the result of mutate is based on the values in the row, so you shouldn't end up with the same value in each row.

Comment: @MrFlick fair enough.  I had a thought in my head, was unable to express it clearly.  It's been removed from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to define the vector of quantile, q.

Example :

mydata$pvalue <- ppois(q=mydata$age, lambda=lambda.age, lower=FALSE)